# Doing a regression with sklearn decision trees with multiple input factors produces error

Tags: python, input, scikit-learn, regression

I want do a regression with the decision tree regressor from sklearn. My input data consists of multiple sensor data, I divided the time series into smaller windows and calculated the mean and the standard deviation for each time window and each sensor. The array looks like this (as an example for two sensors and 100 time windows):

```py
features_x = np.array([[x[:,0].mean(), x[:,0].std(), x[:,1].mean(), x[:,1].std()]
                    for x in np.array_split(train_array, 100)])
```

Then I want to predict the mean of a third sensor:

```py
features_y = np.array([[x[:,2].mean()]
                        for x in np.array_split(train_array, 100)])
```

Then I'm using the decision tree regressor:

```py
clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf.fit(features_x.reshape(-1,1),features_y.reshape(-1,1))
```

But when I use this code I get an error message:

```
ValueError: Number of labels does not match number of samples
```

This must be because I use an array with 4 "values" as input but an array with only 1 "value" as output. But I actually want to use the data from a lot of sensors as input to predict the value of only one other sensor as output. Is there a possibility to make the regression work that way?

Edit: Both feature matrices consist of float values. features_x has 4 columns and 100 rows, each column is a mean or a standard deviation. Each row is one time window.
features_y has 1 column and 100 rows. I just calculate the mean for one sensor in every time window.

Comment: What do you mean by `values`? The number of features has to stay the same, but the number of samples can differ, that's just how any fitting works. You might be able to use some transformations to make sure this is the case. Please add a bit more detail to your code, such as the shapes of your arrays and descriptions of what they are.

Comment: @user2653663 Sorry, if it wasn't clear, with values I mean the two means and the two standard deviations, I use in the matrix features_x. So, I have to transform those four values into like one single value? So that I am able to predict y? I will add some more details :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you use the reshape function on your input:

```
clf.fit(features_x.reshape(-1,1),features_y.reshape(-1,1))
```

The array `features_x` has multiple columns and after this reshape it has only one column with all the elements, so it becomes longer than `features_y` and hence the error. To give you a better picture of what is going on consider this example:

```
In [4]: a = np.zeros(8).reshape((4,2))                                                                        

In [5]: a                                                                                                     
Out[5]: 
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])

In [6]: a.reshape(-1,1)                                                                                       
Out[6]: 
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
```

You can use `.shape` property of any numpy array to verify the format of your input and labels.

Answer (score 0):

Your features_y ends being a numpy array of lists, but you only need an array of floats, try to work with:

```
features_y = np.array([x[:,2].mean() for x in np.array_split(train_array, 100)])
```

Also, pay attention to the reshape method.

```
features_y = np.array([[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]])
features_y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Outputs:

```
array([[1],[1],[1], ...])
```

But reshape of x:

```
features_x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
features_x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Outputs:

```
array([[1],[1],[1],...])
```

You do not want to reshape your features_x, the structure provided is correct.